# Is this a schefflera plant?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I thought maybe a schefflera but not sure. Waxy leaves and some look like they have serrated tips.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to know from the information provided. Some details say it could be, but there are other plants that might qualify as well. Consider [this picture](http://www.floragreatlakes.info/html/rfspecies/hypoglauca.html) for example, that of a woody vine (Cissus hypoglauca) in Australia and there may well be others with palmate 5 leaflets.

Arguments no: normally by this size Brassaia actinophylla (Schefflera) has started producing palmate leaves with more than 5 leaflets. While 5 might be good on a very young plant the normal count is 7 or more, and most of the images of young leaves I have viewed don't have that purple coloration at the tip of the petiole and into the leaf veins.

Arguments yes: leaf shape is right, seem to be thick and glossy on long petioles and the very young leaves are not completely reddish. We could go into a discussion of sap differences but I don't want to go there since Schefflera sap contact is something you want to avoid. It's a diagnostic test that has a high potential cost.

So really you need to wait for a bit more to happen. Either it produces the kind of bark expected on Schefflera or it turns into a vine with tendrils or something else. You might add a few details to your question, such as the description/source of the seed, your rough location, closeup of any bark visible at this stage.

Comment: Agreed, what I was looking for in the picture, but could not see was some trunk material to help indicate. My immediate reaction is that it is not because the leaves are pretty big for a juvenile scheffalara